# class Date in Java - cannot find symbol

Tags: java

With code:
`String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss").format(new Date());`

I get:

```
cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Date
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss").format(new Date());
```

Why?

My imports:

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
```

Comment: import java.util.Date

Comment: This is actually a reasonably-written question (you have included all the necessary information), but you are likely to get downvotes for your lack of research effort. I Googled `java date() import` and the [first hit](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_date_time.htm) showed me that you need to import `java.util.Date`. To avoid getting downvoted and closed in future, you might want to Google first. [This website](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) should also help you out with a few things that people will expect you to have done before asking for help. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're simply missing this:
`import java.util.Date;`

Answer (score 8):

Add this import.

```
import java.util.Date;
```

It won't show any errors.

Java Doc: [Date class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) documentation, (see link for extra info).